# Safer k128 key schedule

Tags: cryptography, key-generation

Can someone explain to me how safer 128's key schedule works? there are many parts that make no sense because they were not described at all in the [paper (pages 3 and 5 in the pdf)](http://tlapixqui.izt.uam.mx/sem_cripto/safer/SaferK64.pdf).

The second paragraph in part 2 is basically the same sentence 3 times. he doesnt describe how the subkeys are put together, as shown in the diagram on page 5. What does the horzonal bracket thing mean? for all i know, it is like a circuit diagram, and it is a jump of some sort. it seems to be neither add nor xor. so what is it?

also, the first bit rotation says **Rotate Each Byte Right by 3 Bits**, but the rest of them say **Rotate Each Byte Left by 6 Bits**. how does that allow for both halves to generate the same subkeys?

and yes, i know safer is not safe. im just doing this to learn how the different algorithms work

Answer (score 1):

Page 239 in that PDF has a Turbopascal program of Safer, including the key schedule. So I would start there (the author himself says

> Appendix B contains a TURBO PASCAL program that implements encryption for the full r-round SAFER K-128 cipher. This program should be taken as the official definition of the SAFER K-128 encryption algorithm.

on page 214....)